# Text shadow on text but not strikethrough

Tags: css

I have a submit button

`<input type="submit" id="addToCart" value="Add to cart">`

with the following styling:

```
text-shadow:
3px 3px 0 #000,
-1px -1px 0 #000,  
1px -1px 0 #000,
-1px 1px 0 #000,
1px 1px 0 #000;
text-decoration: line-through;
```

But the issue is that the strikethrough line has the text shadow too. Is there a way to separate it so that the text has the drop shadow but not the strikethrough?

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/cxJ4a/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When all else fails, cheat like crazy.

```
#addToCart {
    position: relative;
}

#addToCart:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
}
```

You may need to fiddle with the margin and border to account for the line height of the button, padding, etc.

edit: Note that this doesn't work with `<input>`, because it's a replaced element...  but it *does* work with `<button>`, which is a more-or-less regular HTML container.

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: sure, sorry.  it uses the `:before` pseudo-element, which is normally just some text that appears before the "real" element, but in this case is a block with no height and a solid horizontal border.  you end up with a solid white line without needing additional markup.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have worked, I've set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cxJ4a/

Comment: hmm, it works here.  maybe this is pickier about browser than i thought.  what are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome, it's the same in Safari as well, and it's still got the shadow in firefox but not half as bad and Opera is gives a retarded result

Comment: oh, pardon.  this works with `<button>`, but not with `<input>`, because `:before` renders inside the element and `<input>` is a replaced element.  switch to `<button>` and you should be fine.  (also remember to remove the `text-decoration`!)  fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cxJ4a/1/